# $X$ and $Y$ have Joint density, what is $c$?

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have joint density $f(x,y)=c(x+y)$ for $0<x$, $y<1$. Now my question is, what is $c$? I tried to solve, which is reasonable in my opinion. But it don't seem to work:
\begin{align}
\int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_0^1 f(x,y)\  dx\  dy = \int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_0^1 c(x+y) \ dy\ dx = \int\limits_0^\infty \big[cxy + \frac{1}{2}cy^2 \big]^{y=1}_{y=0}\  dx = \int\limits_0^\infty cx + \frac{1}{2}c \ dx.
\end{align}
What to do, are the restrictions on $x$ related to $y$?

Comment: The joint density function "lives" on the square $S$ with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$, so you need the double integral $\iint_S c(x+y)\,dy\,dx$. Express as an iterated integral. If you draw the square, the limits will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

I quess you should take the first integral between $0$ and $1$, by the condition $0 <x,y<1$. Then you would get: $$1= \int_0^1 \int_0^1f(x,y) dx dy = \int_0^1 cx +\frac{1}{2}c dx = [cx^2+\frac{1}{2}cx]_0^1=\frac{3}{2}c$$.

This implies $c= \frac{2}{3}$.

N.B. I would have posted a comment, but my reputation doesn't allow it.

Greetings